# Failed to connect to thirdpartydomain.com.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

Please am having curl error while connecting to another website.

Using on postman, I got the desired response but on my webserver, its giving this error

**Failed to connect to mydomain.com port 443: Connection timed out**

I copied the exact script postman generated, pasted on my webserver, I got the error message still.

I suspected my webserver could be the issue, so I tried with different webservers (upto 3 different servers), the error still persist.

Please what am I doing wrong?

Here's my curl script

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'https://mythirdpartydomain.com';
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX233XXX',
'content-length : 86'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
echo curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: `content-length : 86` - why? You are not sending an actual request body, as far as I can see?

Comment: Thank you CBroe for your suggestions. I tried both ways still couldn't get desire results.